# SQL Self/Inner Join from same table

Tags: sql, join

I'm struggling with applying a simple JOIN command for this table (office):

```
+-----------+-------+------+
| Employee  | Name  | Boss |
+-----------+-------+------+
|         1 | Joe   |    2 |
|         2 | Chris |    3 |
|         3 | Rob   |    2 |
|         4 | Dean  |    1 |
+-----------+-------+------+
```

I've seen numerous examples where 2 tables are being used, which I tried to reproduce, which let me to this:

```sql
SELECT office.Name
FROM office
INNER JOIN office
    ON office.Employee = office.Boss;
```

I'm trying to refer an employee to it's boss

But this code gives me: Not unique table/alias: 'office'
What simple solution is there? Maybe without even using JOIN at all..

Comment: Your sample data has Chris and Rob being each other's boss - is that correct?

Comment: Also, why is the table named `office` when it contains information pertaining to people?

Comment: Use table aliases!

Comment: "I'm trying to refer an employee to it's boss" - using a self `JOIN` only works for single references btw - if you want to find out who someone's top-boss is you'll need a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use table aliases, because you have multiple tables with the same name in the query. For example:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Name
FROM office a
INNER JOIN office b
    ON a.Employee = b.Boss;
```

In this case the query includes two "instances" of the table `office`. To make sure you are using the right columns belonging to the right tables, you need to use table aliases for each instance; in this case `a`  and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AS` keyword (in the `FROM` clause) to give each table its own distinct alias:

```
SELECT
    employee.Name AS ThisPerson,
    boss.Name     AS HasThisBoss
FROM
    office AS employee
    INNER JOIN office AS boss ON
        boss.Employee = employee.Boss;
```

---

FYI: the `AS` keyword in SQL is overloaded and has very different purposes depending on the context:

- Column alias: `SELECT foo.X AS bar FROM qux`
- Table alias: `SELECT foo.X FROM qux AS foo`
- Computed column: `ALTER TABLE foo ADD bar AS ( X + Y )`
- Type specifier in `CAST`: `SELECT CAST( x AS int ) AS x2`